# UITextView hidding text while typing

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextview

I see some very strange behavior. I have a text view displayed inside a view which is part of a scroll view. If when I start typing in the text view, the keyboard would normally hide that text view, then I animate the text view and push it above the keyboard so that it stays visible. If I do that, the third and subsequent rows that I type are not visible until I dismiss the keyboard at which moment I can see the text I typed. If, when I start typing in the text view, I don't need to animate it to push it up (because the keyboard does not hides it), then I can see all the text I type, hence my problem only arises when text view is animated.

Below is my code that creates the text view:

```
    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    textView.delegate = self;
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1; 
    textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    [self addSubview:textView];
    [textView release];
```

Below is the code that animates the text view:

```
- (void) makeTextViewVisible: (UITextView *)textArea up:(BOOL) up {

if (up) {
    animatedDistance = 0;

    CGPoint myPoint = [textArea.superview convertPoint:textArea.frame.origin toView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        animatedDistance = PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT - (950 - myPoint.y) + 150;
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        animatedDistance = PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT + (PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT - myPoint.y);   
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        animatedDistance = myPoint.x - LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT + 120;
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        animatedDistance = LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT - myPoint.x + 100; 
    }

    if (animatedDistance < 0) {
        animatedDistance = 0.0; 
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = textArea.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [textArea setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

} 
else {
    CGRect viewFrame = textArea.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [textArea setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];      
}
```

I tried calling setNeedsDisplay/setNeedsLayout inside textViewDidChange, but with no luck.

Anybody encountered this problem before, or know how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts for you.  First, I think you're working too hard with the animatedDistance calculation.  I usually create a master view rather than working with the UIWindow's dimensions (which don't rotate with the device).  Otherwise, as you've discovered, you have to take into consideration the status bar, the phone status bar, etc.  Using the view allows you to reduce all those calculations down to one (just compensating for the two different keyboard heights):

```
if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)|| (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    keyboardHeight = LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT;
} else {
    keyBoardHeight = PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT; 
}

CGPoint myPoint = [self.view convertPoint:textArea.frame.origin toView:self.view];
float windowHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;

animatedDistance = myPoint.y+textArea.bounds.size.height+keyboardHeight-windowHeight;   

if (animatedDistance < 0) {
    animatedDistance = 0.0; 
}
```

So using the view's bounds gets you the info you need.

Secondly, why move the textView? Why not just adjust the scrollPos of your scroll window?

Third, you refer to the textView being inside a view which is inside a scrollview (although I don't see that in the code).  It's possible your textView is being clipped by the middle view's boundaries, which would lead to being able to type in it, but not being able to see the results. Can you see the boundaries of your textView?

Finally, as an aesthetic point, animatedDistance is a state variable, you should set animatedDistance to zero in your else branch after you've put the animation back.  That way, if you call makeTextViewVisible:textView UP:false twice for some reason, it won't mess you up.

Comment: Very useful points you make. I like the second idea of adjusting the scroll position.